# Type mismatch when calling userform

Tags: vba, userform, type-mismatch, import-module

I'm sure this is something simple, but I have looked all over and cannot find an explanation.  Surely, plenty of other people would like to move modules and a userform to another workbook.  I exported 3 modules and 1 userform and then imported them into a new workbook.  The userform name that was exported was "NUI" and when I look at the properties in the new workbook after importing the name is still "NUI".  However, now when I try to run the sub to show the userform, I get a run-time data mismatch error and NUI is highlighted in the line NUI.StartUpPosition.  Any ideas why this no longer works?  Is there some sort of link that needs to be broken?  Does the module still try to find some userform NUI in other files?  If I delete the userform in the new workbook and add a new userform, when I try to name it NUI, it tells me the name is in use.  Any ideas?

```
Sub CallUserForm()
    '  Calls UserFrom NUI and centers it to excel window whether it is full screen or not.
    PO.Unprotect Password:="1234"
    PO.Activate

    NUI.StartUpPosition = 0
    NUI.Top = Application.Top + 125
    NUI.Left = Application.Left + Application.Width / 2 - NUI.Width / 2
    NUI.Show
    PO.Protect Password:="1234"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried what you describe (export form and module, import into a new spreadsheet).  It worked fine for me.  However: I wonder if you may have accidentally imported the copy of the form into the original file (instead of the new one).

If I delete the form from the new file, I get the same error you did, so check that you actually did import to the new location.